# How do I use a Vue3 Pinia store inside the methods of a component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I can't seem to find the answer to this simple question. In all the examples and tutorials for the Pinia store, the store is referenced in the setup of a component, and then used in the template part of the component:

```
<script setup>
  import {useUserStore} from "@/stores/UserStore.js";
  const store = useUserStore();
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ store }}</h1>
</template>
```

This is all good, but if I use the store in a component method and call that method from the template section:

```
<script>
export default {
  methods:
  {
    methodExample() {
      console.log(store);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

I get the error:
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: store is not defined.

I can't seem to find a single example where the store is used not in the template part but in the methods of the script part. What am I missing?

Many thanks

Comment: In your second `<script>` you aren't importing your store and assigning the result of `useUserStore()` but it's a separate script. You might consider combining them, which is the more common way I see composition used with Vue 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example, through the use of computed:

```
<script>
import {useUserStore} from "@/stores/UserStore.js";

export default {
  computed: {
    store: () => useUserStore();
  }, 
  methods:
  {
    methodExample() {
      console.log(this.store);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: store is still not defined

Comment: Yes, you're right. misspell. the "this" context is added when calling

Answer (score 1):

Pinia store is technically a composable, so you need to use it as such.

I am a bit confused if you are using Options API or Composition API for your component

To use it with Options API - you need to return store from `setup()` function ([playground](https://play.pinia.vuejs.org/#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))

```
<script lang="ts">
import { useStore } from './counter.ts'

export default {
  setup () {
    const store = useStore()
    return { store }
  },
  methods: {
    increment () {
      this.store.n++
    }
  }
}

</script>

<template>
  <button @click="increment">Increment {{ store.n }}</button>
</template>
```

If you are using Composition API - just use the instance returned by `useStore()` ([playground](https://play.pinia.vuejs.org/#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))

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useStore } from './counter.ts'

const store = useStore()
function increment () {
  store.n++
}

</script>

<template>
  <button @click="increment">Increment {{ store.n }}</button>
</template>
```

You have to pick either Options API or Composition API. If you have both `script` and `script setup` - you need to pick one for your component to have better developer experience. You don't have to match style across all components, but it is usually a good idea to have consistency

UPD: After Estus Flask comment, I looked into Pinia docs a bit, and they have some methods exported that you can use in Options API https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/options-api.html

Comment: It's unnecessary to use setup function. Using it together with options api may result in undocumented and unpredictable behavour

Comment: @EstusFlask that is officially documented way of using composables in Options API  https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables#using-composables-in-options-api

Comment: Pinia docs also states that `useStore` should be called either in `script setup` or within `setup()` https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Using-the-store

Comment: I see, they covered this part. As a rule of thumb, a composable needs to be called during setup, this depends on its implementation. This includes hooks that occur at the same time - data(), beforeCreate(), created(). It's normal to use composables in these hooks. As for pinia, the docs doesn't mention "should" because this wouldn't be true, setup() is used for consistency in that example. Due to how pinia stores are implemented, they can be used anywhere after pinia has been initialized, including a computed, as shown in another answer.